# What should getObjByName() return?

Tags: c++, return, return-value, class-design

I was working on some c++ code like this:

```
//c++ code
class MovieInfo;

MovieInfo getMovieInfoByName(String movieName)
{
    //search the movieInfoList with movieName
    if(FOUND)
        return movieInfo;
    //TODO: **what should i return if the movieInfo can't be found in the list?**
}
```

The question is what should i return if the movieInfo can't be found in the list?

Comment: You can't return anything. Either raise an exception or else change the function to return some type that has a value that can indicate "not found". An iterator or a Boost.Optional are common choices.

Comment: Or return `std::pair<bool, MovieInfo>`, set first to true if it's found.

Comment: @billz: and what do you set the second to if it's not found? But yes, a `pair` can act as a feeble Optional if absolutely necessary.

Comment: maybe `MovieInfo` holds a flag that says `Invalid`. if so, it would be no problem to return the invalid object. otherwise like steve said, exception would be fitting

Comment: @SteveJessop If return a pair, it will be a default MovieInfo object and disgarded if pair.first is false. I doubt let MovieInfo carray a flag is a good choice.

Comment: @billz: sure, if there's such a thing as a default `MovieInfo` object. It might not have a no-args constructor, though, the question is a bit under-specced given that it asks us what value to return of an incomplete type! I suppose if all else fails you could specify that "Die Hard" is the default movie, that always used to be what we'd end up watching when nobody could agree on a DVD.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'd agree "Die Hard" are good movies :D

Answer (score 5):

You have several options:

- Define the `MovieInfo` class such that an "invalid" instance is possible (similarly to how a default-constructed `std::thread` doesn't represent an actual thread) and return such an instance.
- Make it a precondition of `getMovieInfoByName()` that the name corresponds to a valid movie info, and simply return a random value if it doesn't (as "violating preconditions leads to undefined behaviour").
- Throw an exception when the name is not found.
- Return something like [`boost::optional<MovieInfo>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).
- Give `getMovieInfoByName()` an extra parameter of type `MovieInfo` which would be used as the return value in case no match for the name is found.

It all depends on your intended use of the function.

Comment: +1: I'd recommend the exception in this case; the name `getMovieInfoByName` suggests that no movie info existing might be an "exceptional" condition. Then again, it might not be one. Even then, I'm not one of these people that insists exceptions _must_ only be used for what is deemed by someone to be an "exceptional" case, just because the words are similar in English.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I prefer to say that if a certain case throws an exception then *by definition* it is exceptional. To defeat semantic nonsense, we must become semantic nonsense ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I shall use this!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context and preconditions that must be met. For example if you are not sure whether the list contains such a movie by the time you call it, then it would be reasonable to do:

```
bool getMovieInfoByName(const std::string& movieName, MovieInfo& movieInfo)
{
    ...
    if (FOUND) {
        movieInfo = ...;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

since the caller will most likely have to know whether the movie with such a movie exists or not.

If it shouldn't happen that `getMovieInfoByName` will not find the movie, i.e. the caller should already know whether the list contains such a movie by other means, then it is perfectly reasonable to throw an exception since it is exceptional state and rather indicates the wrong usage of this method.

There's also a design pattern called **[Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)**, which is based on constructing an object, state of which can indicate whether it is a valid / initialized object or it is a dummy instance representing NULL.
In this case the caller would most likely still have to check whether appropriate `MovieInfo` instance has been returned and this class should provide a method such as `bool isValid();`.